# C input issue when creating new data structure

Tags: c

I have a simple program here where function create_truck needs to return truck data structure which I named as lol, and my question is that why this line `struct truck lol = { asd, length, weight, crg };` won't take `asd` as an input.
This needs to be done without dynamical allocation and copy of a string 'name' is needed to be done. And I have to keep the function parameters as they are + the data structures cargo and truck are actually in header file but just to not be too complicated I posted this code like this.

My code:

```
//Cargo: what the truck is carrying
struct cargo {
    const char *title;
    int quantity;
    double weight;
};

// Define the truck structure here
struct truck {
    char *name;
    double length;
    double weight;
    struct cargo crg;
};


struct truck create_truck(const char *name, double length, double weight,
    struct cargo crg) {
    char asd[31];
    strncpy(asd, name, 31);

/*here is my problem, this command below wont take my string asd
  as a valid input*/
    struct truck lol = { asd, length, weight, crg };
    return lol;
}

/*This function is just for printing the parts of the data structure I made*/
void print_truck(const struct truck *car) {
    printf("%s\n", car->name);
    printf("%.1lf\n", car->length);
    printf("%.1lf\n", car->weight);
    printf("%s\n", car->crg.title);
    printf("%d\n", car->crg.quantity);
    printf("%.1lf\n", car->crg.weight);

}

int main()
{
    /* testing exercise. Feel free to modify */
    struct cargo c = { "Bananas", 10000, 1500 };

    struct truck t = create_truck("Mercedes-Benz Actros", 12.0, 12.5, c);

    print_truck(&t);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Array `asd` is invalid once `create_truck()` returns.  Unwise to return `lol` based on the address of  `asd`.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: As @chux said, you are using are point to a local var that is going out of scope. I tried running this but changing `asd` to be allocated on the heap using `malloc` and it worked fine.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  when posting a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, please post a [mcve] so we can recreate (and debug) the problem.

Comment: If you have arbitrary restrictions on the solution (aka homework), then you should clearly state what those restrictions are in your question. As it is, you are wasting the answerers' time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach:

```
char asd[31];
strncpy(asd, name, 31);
```

is that `asd` will not exist once the function returns since `asd` is just a local array.

The solution given by `Eziz` is also wrong.

```
struct truck create_truck(const char *name, double length, double weight, struct cargo crg) {
    char *asd;

    if( (asd = malloc( strlen(name)+1 )) == NULL ) {
        printf( "Memory error!\n" );
        exit( 0 );
    }
    strcpy(asd, name);

    struct truck lol = { asd, length, weight, crg };

    free(asd); // free here (wrong)

    return lol;
}
```

Once we free `asd` your `char * name` in
struct truck {

```
char *name; // POINTER TO A MEMORY
//...
}
```

points to the freed memory!

What you need is to make sure that `char *name` points to valid memory holding the name, than all what you need is:

```
struct truck create_truck(char *name, double length, double weight, struct cargo crg)
{
    struct truck lol = { name, length, weight, crg };
    return lol;
}
```

The test program is below, let me know if it works for you.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Cargo: what the truck is carrying
struct cargo {
    const char *title;
    int quantity;
    double weight;
};

// Define the truck structure here
struct truck {
    char *name;       // has to point to a valid memory holding the name
    double length;
    double weight;
    struct cargo crg;
};

struct truck create_truck(char *name, double length, double weight, struct cargo crg)
{
    struct truck lol = { name, length, weight, crg };
    return lol;
}

/*This function is just for printing the parts of the data structure I made*/
void print_truck(const struct truck *car) {

    printf("%s\n", car->name);
    printf("%.1lf\n", car->length);
    printf("%.1lf\n", car->weight);
    printf("%s\n", car->crg.title);
    printf("%d\n", car->crg.quantity);
    printf("%.1lf\n\n", car->crg.weight);
}

int main()
{
    struct cargo c = { "Bananas", 10000, 1500 };
    //1.    
    char name1[] = { 'F', 'O', 'R','D', 0};
    //2.
    char *name2 = "TOYOTA"; 
    //3.
    char *name3 = (char[]){'M', 'I', 'N', 'I', 0};
    //4.
    size_t len4 = strlen("LADA") + 1;
    char *name4 = malloc(len4*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(name4,"LADA");  

    //5. warning: strdup is not part of the C or C++ standard, it's a POSIX function.
    char *name5 = strdup("HONDA");  

    // 0.
    struct truck t = create_truck("Mercedes-Benz Actros", 12.0, 12.5, c);
    print_truck(&t);

    // 1.
    struct truck t1 = create_truck(name1, 12.0, 12.5, c);
    print_truck(&t1);

    // 2.
    struct truck t2 = create_truck(name2, 12.0, 12.5, c);
    print_truck(&t2);

    // 3.
    struct truck t3 = create_truck(name3, 12.0, 12.5, c);
    print_truck(&t3);

    // 4.
    struct truck t4 = create_truck(name4, 12.0, 12.5, c);
    print_truck(&t4);

    // 5.
    struct truck t5 = create_truck(name5, 12.0, 12.5, c);
    print_truck(&t5);


    free(name4);
    free(name5);

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the program:

```
Mercedes-Benz Actros                                                                                                         
12.0                                                                                                                         
12.5                                                                                                                         
Bananas                                                                                                                      
10000                                                                                                                        
1500.0                                                                                                                       

FORD                                                                                                                         
12.0                                                                                                                         
12.5                                                                                                                         
Bananas                                                                                                                      
10000                                                                                                                        
1500.0                                                                                                                       

TOYOTA                                                                                                                       
12.0                                                                                                                         
12.5                                                                                                                         
Bananas                                                                                                                      
10000                                                                                                                        
1500.0 

MINI                                                                                                                         
12.0                                                                                                                         
12.5                                                                                                                         
Bananas                                                                                                                      
10000                                                                                                                        
1500.0                                                                                                                       

LADA                                                                                                                         
12.0                                                                                                                         
12.5                                                                                                                         
Bananas                                                                                                                      
10000                                                                                                                        
1500.0                                                                                                                       

HONDA                                                                                                                        
12.0                                                                                                                         
12.5                                                                                                                         
Bananas                                                                                                                      
10000                                                                                                                        
1500.0
```

Comment: for me this is crashing the program, and that's why I need to make a copy of the string 'name' @sg7

Comment: @michael Please run the presented solution. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in `strncpy`. If you get the name of truck with dynamic memory allocation, the function works fine:

```
struct truck create_truck(const char *name, double length, double weight, struct cargo crg) {
    char *asd;

    if( (asd = malloc( strlen(name)+1 )) == NULL ) {
        printf( "Memory error!\n" );
        exit( 0 );
    }

    strcpy(asd, name);

    struct truck lol = { asd, length, weight, crg };
    free(asd); // free here
    return lol;
}
```

Comment: Yea but this way the program leaks memory right? cause there isn't freeing asd.. Why does not the same thing without dynamic memory allocation work? cause I should do this without dynamic memory allocation @Eziz Durdyyev

Comment: because the cargo and truck data structures are actually in header file and the code outside of create_truck cannot free any memory allocated in function create_truck, I just writed the code here like that to not go too complicated @Eziz Durdyyev

Comment: @michael aaa I see

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate `struct truck` on the stack in `main()` you should provide a pointer to it in the call to `crate_truck()` (and perhaps rename `create_truck()` to `initaialize_truck()` since it doesn't actually create it). Something like this:

```
void initialize_truck(struct truck* lol,const char *name, double length, double weight,struct cargo* crg){
    lol->name = strdup(name);
    lol->length = length;
    lol->weight = weight;
    /* This is kind of a hack, you should either deep copy or just have a pointer to cargo. */
    memcpy(&lol->crg,crg,sizeof(struct cargo));
}

main(){
    struct cargo c = { "Bananas", 10000, 1500 };
    struct truck t;
    initialize_truck(&t, "Mercedes-Benz Actros", 12.0, 12.5, &c);
    print_truck(&t);
    return 0;
}
```

Or, as an alternative, dymamically allocate `struct truck` instead of putting it on the stack:

```
struct truck create_truck(const char *name, double length, double weight,struct cargo* crg){
    struct truck* lol = (struct truck*)malloc(sizeof(struct truck));
    lol->name = strdup(name);
    lol->length = length;
    lol->weight = weight;
    /* This is kind of a hack, you should either deep copy or just have a pointer to cargo. */
    memcpy(&lol->crg,crg,sizeof(struct cargo));
    return lol;
}

main(){
    struct cargo c = { "Bananas", 10000, 1500 };
    struct truck* t = create_truck("Mercedes-Benz Actros", 12.0, 12.5, &c);
    print_truck(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to do this without dynamically allocating, and I have to also keep the create_truck function parameters as they are so both of those examples are  not working for me ..